# FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. TypeError: req.next is not a function

Tags: node.js, express, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ejs

I am stuck in Firebase Warning. 
Can any one please assist me here ?

Error: TypeError: req.next is not a function

**Below is my database structure:**
[image: my data structure]

**Below is the my code:**

```
var user = null;
user = req.session.user,
user_id = req.session.user_id;
session = req.session;
session.admin = 1;
session.current = 'subscription';
var db = firebase.database();
var ref = null;
var unix = Math.round(+new Date()/1000);

if(req.body.url) {
    // Code for update particular state from the country
    console.log(req.body);
    ref = db.ref().child(req.body.url);
    ref.on("value",function(snapshot) {
        //res.send(snapshot.ref);
        ref.child(req.body.city_name).remove();
    });

    console.log("Log History :");
    console.log("/countryMaster/" + req.body.country_name + "/countyMaster");
    console.log(req.body);
    db = firebase.database();
    ref = db.ref().child("/countryMaster/" + req.body.country_name + "/countyMaster").child(req.body.state_name).set({
        "createBy": "",
        "createDate": unix,
        "status": "1",
        "updateBy": "",
        "updateDate": unix
    });



}else {
    // Code for Add particular state from the country
    var ref = db.ref().child("/countryMaster/" + req.body.country + "/countyMaster").child(req.body.state_name).set({
        "createBy": "",
        "createDate": unix,
        "status": "1",
        "updateBy": "",
        "updateDate": unix
    });
}
res.redirect('/city');
```

Comment: Where are you calling this snippet of code from? I can tell it's a router handler/controller action, but it may help us if you post where you're calling this snippet of code from.

Comment: I am calling this snippet from the user.js route. In user.js route i have one function called saveCity. In this code i am writing to delete the existing record and insert new one for update the key in firebase.

Comment: Post the full source. The error you're getting is correct, `req.next` does not exist on the `req` object which means you are calling `req.next` somewhere in code, but not in the snippet you posted above.